# The volume enclosing the charge in Gauss's law: does it have to be simply connected?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, capacitance, gauss-law, topology

I was trying to apply Gauss's law to a simple problem: Find the capacitance of a cylindrical capacitor. Inner radius is $a$ and outer radius is $c$. The space between the plates is a dielectric material with permittivity $\epsilon_r$ from radius **a** upto **b** < **c**. The rest of the space is air. I'm assuming that the electric field has radial symmetry. To find the electric field inside the dielectric material, is it okay if I use a toroidal-like volume that encloses the outer cylindrical plate? The surface has two curved parts parallel to the capacitor plates of inner radius **r** and outer radius **c** and two flat parts perpendicular to the curved surfaces. Does it matter that it is not simply connected?

Comment: The problem is you then have to integrate the field over the toroidal shape, it's better to use a surface sharing the same symmetries as the geometry of the problem

Comment: Can you show an image? I cannot image what configuration are youtalking about.